# VLC failing in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, vlc

I am having an issue with VLC on a fresh install of Kubuntu 19.04.  When double clicking a video from Dolphin VLC will run once.  However, if I close VLC and double click a new file, VLC will not run.  I may see the VLC show briefly in the panel with a spinning indicator then it closes and the interface never shows.  If I run VLC from the command line, it launches and runs fine.  I can drag videos to it and they will always play.  If I reboot, it will run once and the issue reappears.  I tried installing a different file manager and the same issue occurs.  I have tried resetting VLC, uninstalling and removing VLC with apt, I have even tried the snap version, all with the same issues.  I have searched the web and tried various things, which I havent kept track of...  Obviously, none of the solutions worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably VLC apparently closes but it doesn't, its process is still running in the background. It's happening to me in Ubuntu-Mate. Next time when it doesn't open after running once try opening system monitor and if there's a VLC process hanging there kill it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by opening Dolphin and right-clicking the file and selecting `Properties`.  Then on the `General` tab selecting `File Typee Options`. From that `General` tab, in the `Application Preference Order` section, I clicked on `VLC media player` and clicked `Edit`.  From there, I clicked on the `Application` tab and edited the `Command` string.  I removed

> --started-from-file

from

> /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U

Leaving only

> /usr/bin/vlc %U

Launching VLC by double-clicking a video in Dolphin has worked perfectly now.  I havent compared it to another Kubuntu system, either.  I suppose I should.  I had already removed the other file manager, so I dont know if the issue would crop up there, but at least I have an idea on what to fix.

I havent looked into *why* this change made it work, but it does, so Im happy for now.

Comment: I just want to point out that your answer is not a solution, rather a workaround. As stated by @GabrielaGarcia , when you click the close icon, the UI is going to close but the process remains active, and you will need to kill it. With your workaround, you force VLC to launch a new process for each video file: when you close the windows, the processes still remains active, sucking up memory. You really need to be careful about the number of processes you are going to launch, and every so often take the time to kill them manually! A quicker way is to close VLC with the keys "CTRL+q".

Comment: @Davide_sd feel free to offer me a real solution then :)

Comment: @Davide_sd What you say doesn't happen for me. I made the suggested change, opened multiple video files (each starting a VLC process) then I closed them and all processes were finished properly.

Comment: This workaround doesn't work for me, still having running VLC process in background and VLC icon in KDE tray (Kubuntu 20.04). [Changing video output from "automatic" to "XVideo (XCB)"](https://askubuntu.com/a/1284651/63516) solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem as OP - and even trying to kill the process in top or in ksysguard was not working for me.

Last night I tried closing down baloorunner and then VLC worked perfectly - IE it closed when pressing the close button on the GUI, no need to kill it, and I could once again double click files in Dolphin to have them open in VLC, as it should be!

So this is a possible work-around I think? It would be cool if anyone else could confirm if it works for them, too!

Comment: after a few more days, i see that what i posted above was not consistent behavior. The problem happens intermittently, and the best work around for me is closing the process from ksysguard (which usually takes at least 30 seconds, it's not instant as it should be). After this, opening from file is again no problem.