# vlc doesn't run again after quit

Tags: vlc

When I open a media with vlc, it works nice until I close the window.
After closing it, it resist on memory and double clicking on any media on my system doesn't open it for playing.

I can kill it with System Monitor or Terminal command. After doing this, everything works again until I close vlc.

I have read  [VLC doesn't open when double-clicking file on Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902605/vlc-doesnt-open-when-double-clicking-file-on-nautilus) but the solutions don't fix my problem. I doubt that the problem is the same.

I'm tired of killing vlc again and again.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you live with :  `alias vlc='pkill vlc;/usr/bin/vlc'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably a problem with the OpenGL drivers (or Mesa graphics library. See issue: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/116). You should change the video output mode.

Go to *`Tools > Preferences > Video`* and then set the value for `Output` field to `XVideo output (XCB)`.

Comment: This one solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: This is solved my problem. Really I couldn't verify the problem is OpenGL driver. My previous value for `output` is `Automatic`. Thanks @xyres.

Comment: @mece1390 For `Automatic` output, VLC uses OpenGL if your GPU supports it.

Answer (score 1):

On Kubuntu 20.04, same thing BUT can NOT kill VLC process from system monitor.
have to right click file in the monitor and "send signal" and choose kill